# kubectl - How to get the list of all pods that have been restarted at least once

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` provides the list of all pods. The column `RESTARTS` shows the number of restarts that a pod has had. How to get the list of all the pods that have had at least one restart? Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | awk '$5>0'
```

or simply just

```
kubectl get po -A | awk '$5>0'
```

Use awk to print if column 5 (RESTARTS) > 0

or with the use of an alias

```
alias k='kubectl'
k get po -A | awk '$5>0'
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept your answer. I would also like to see an answer based on the `kubectl` options without post processing.